# Is it possible to SELECT just an attribute's value from XML or RSS using YQL?

Tags: xml, rss, yql, xml-attribute, google-weather-api

I've got some `YQL` queries from XML and RSS that are returning more than what I want to `SELECT`. I'm getting all the XML from the `itemPath` down to the attribute value, which I then have to sift through to dig out just the values I want:

This query:

```
SELECT current_conditions.temp_c.data FROM xml
    WHERE url="http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=Tbilisi"
    AND itemPath="//weather"
```

returns all this:

```
    <results>
        <weather>
            <current_conditions>
                <temp_c data="-7"/>
            </current_conditions>
        </weather>
    </results>
```

but all I need is:

```
    <results>-7</results>
```

and this query:

```
SELECT condition.temp FROM rss
    WHERE url="http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=1965878&u=c"
```

returns all this:

```
    <results>
        <item>
            <yweather:condition
                xmlns:yweather="http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0" temp="1"/>
        </item>
    </results>
```

whereas what I want is just this:

```
    <results>1</results>
```

**Is there any way to get more concise results like these when selecting XML attributes with YQL so I don't have to parse the result further in my code?**

One use case is when I want to query several sources within one query using `yql.query.multi`. I don't get back a nice neat "row" when all this surrounding XML is returned to me.

Answer (score 1):

What does this give you?

```
SELECT current_conditions.temp_c.data FROM xml
  WHERE url="http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=Tbilisi"
  AND itemPath="//weather/current_conditions/temp_c/@data"
```

Comment: This gives me empty results: `<results/>`

Comment: add `AND compact=html5` to your select statement

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the HTML5 parser. Using @Murry McDonald's answer and modifying it a little should work for you.

```
SELECT current_conditions.temp_c.data FROM xml
  WHERE url="http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=Tbilisi"
  AND itemPath="//weather/current_conditions/temp_c/@data" AND compact="html"
```

Comment: Really? This is an old question and it looks like the API is gone now. I just get a 404 from the URL so the query fails. Does it work for you?

Comment: @hippietrail Yes, you are right. I just saw that it returns a 404. But I was trying to answer your question "select attribute's value using YQL" and this is something that you should be able to do using the above answer.